# Dictionary of nested lists to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm trying to learn how pandas works but I assume I'm missing something obvious.

I have a file looking like this :

```
dict_spl ={'doc1':[[('word11',1,1),('word12',1,2)]], 'doc2':[[('word21',2,1),('word22',2,2)]]}
```

And I'm trying to obtain a `pandas` DataFrame looking like this:

```
# doc1 word11 1 1
# doc1 word12 1 2
# doc2 word21 2 1
# doc2 word22 2 2
```

I haven't found a way to create both new columns and new rows while duplicating the common values.

Comment: How are you passing this to pandas?

Comment: With `pd.DataFrame(dict_spl).T` for instance. Except it obviously doesn't give the result I want.
I'm not sure if it really answers your question.

Comment: Are you able to change your dictionary's structure? If so, you can create the frame you wrote out above by doing: `pd.DataFrame.from_records([('a','a1',1,1),('a', 'a2',1,2), ('b', 'b1',2,1),('b', 'b2',2,2)])`

Comment: No I can't easily change the structure of my dictionary. I obtain it while parsing several documents stored in a DataFrame with `Spacy` and it returns me something looking like `dict_spl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = [[(k, *y) for y in v[0]] for k,v in dict_spl.items()]
a = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list('abcd'))
print (df)
      a       b  c  d
0  doc1  word11  1  1
1  doc1  word12  1  2
2  doc2  word21  2  1
3  doc2  word22  2  2
```

I feel there is better solution, so I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45233422/2901002):

```
#Martijn Pieters♦'s solution
a = [(k, *t) for k, v in dict_spl.items() for t in v[0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list('abcd'))
print (df)
      a       b  c  d
0  doc2  word21  2  1
1  doc2  word22  2  2
2  doc1  word11  1  1
3  doc1  word12  1  2
```

Comment: It works perfectly.
I'll take some time to understand clearly what you've done.
Thank you.

Comment: @JeromeLaurent - Glad can help!