# Convert dict of nested lists to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

I have `dict` of nested `list`s:

```
d = {'a': [[('a1', 1, 1), ('a2', 1, 2)]], 'b': [[('b1', 2, 1), ('b2', 2, 2)]]}
print (d)
{'b': [[('b1', 2, 1), ('b2', 2, 2)]], 'a': [[('a1', 1, 1), ('a2', 1, 2)]]}
```

I need create `list` of `tuple`s like:

```
[('b', 'b1', 2, 1), ('b', 'b2', 2, 2), ('a', 'a1', 1, 1), ('a', 'a2', 1, 2)]
```

I tried:

```
a = [[(k, *y) for y in v[0]] for k,v in d.items()]
a = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

I think my solution is a bit over-complicated. Is there some better, more pythonic, maybe one line solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
[(k, *t) for k, v in d.items() for t in v[0]]
```

The `v[0]` is needed because your values are just single-element lists with another list contained. The above can be expanded to the following nested `for` loops, if you wanted to figure out what it does:

```
for key, value in d.items():   # value is [[(...), (...), ...]]
    for tup in value[0]:  # each (...) from value[0]
        (key, *tup)  # produce a new tuple
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'a': [[('a1', 1, 1), ('a2', 1, 2)]], 'b': [[('b1', 2, 1), ('b2', 2, 2)]]}
>>> [(k, *t) for k, v in d.items() for t in v[0]]
[('a', 'a1', 1, 1), ('a', 'a2', 1, 2), ('b', 'b1', 2, 1), ('b', 'b2', 2, 2)]
```

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: and I find `(k, *t)` to be neater than `(k,) + t`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was using a different formulation. The way you wrote it it would be `[(k,) + t ..`. But i get the point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Is this only python 3 solution? thanks.

Comment: @jezrael: this uses Python 3's iterable expansion syntax, yes. You can make it Python 2 compatible by using `(k,) + t` instead of `(k, *t)`.